# Decrypt string in java which in encrypted in android app

Tags: java, android, string, encryption

I am using this class to encrypt a string in android app

```
public class Encryption {
     public static String encrypt(String seed, String cleartext) throws Exception {
            byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes());
            byte[] result = encrypt(rawKey, cleartext.getBytes());
            return toHex(result);
        }

        public static String decrypt(String seed, String encrypted) throws Exception {
            byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes());
            byte[] enc = toByte(encrypted);
            byte[] result = decrypt(rawKey, enc);
            return new String(result);
        }

        private static byte[] getRawKey(byte[] seed) throws Exception {
            KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
            SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
            sr.setSeed(seed);
            kgen.init(128, sr); // 192 and 256 bits may not be available
            SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();
            byte[] raw = skey.getEncoded();
            return raw;
        }


        private static byte[] encrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] clear) throws Exception {
            SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
            byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(clear);
            return encrypted;
        }

        private static byte[] decrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] encrypted) throws Exception {
            SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
            byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
            return decrypted;
        }

        public static String toHex(String txt) {
            return toHex(txt.getBytes());
        }
        public static String fromHex(String hex) {
            return new String(toByte(hex));
        }

        public static byte[] toByte(String hexString) {
            int len = hexString.length()/2;
            byte[] result = new byte[len];
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
                result[i] = Integer.valueOf(hexString.substring(2*i, 2*i+2), 16).byteValue();
            return result;
        }

        public static String toHex(byte[] buf) {
            if (buf == null)
                return "";
            StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer(2*buf.length);
            for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
                appendHex(result, buf[i]);
            }
            return result.toString();
        }
        private final static String HEX = "0123456789ABCDEF";
        private static void appendHex(StringBuffer sb, byte b) {
            sb.append(HEX.charAt((b>>4)&0x0f)).append(HEX.charAt(b&0x0f));
        }
}
```

I am using above class like this -

```
Encryption.encrypt("password", "some text to be encrypted");
```

Their is no problem in encrypting the string, but when i try to decrypt the encrypted string (*using the same class i posted above*) in external java program (*not in android app*),

```
Encryption.decrypt("password","D4036388D459C4009812FB3F1AE4BB36E4419C97775D");
```

i get this exception -

```
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE_f.b(DashoA13*..)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE_f.b(DashoA13*..)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(DashoA13*..)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(DashoA13*..)
    at Encryption.decrypt(Encryption.java:59)
    at Encryption.decrypt(Encryption.java:32)
    at Encryption.main(Encryption.java:96)
```

I think, this is because i am using same code on different platforms,

But i don't know proper reason why this doesn't work ? and
Is their any way i can decrypt the string in java?

Answer (score 1):

@SteveP is probably right.

Still another problem I see, is the byte[] `getBytes("UTF-8")` (binary data) to String `new String(bytes, "UTF-8")` (text) conversion. On Android the default encoding is UTF-8, on Windows most likely something else.